# DTD element empty and any

Tags: xml, dtd

In a dtd, can an element be defined as

```
<!ELEMENT name (ANY|EMPTY)>
```

meaning that an name can either be like `<name/>` or it can contain any elements that does break xml rules?

Answer (score 2):

No, but if you use the type `ANY`, it can still be empty.

Examples:

```
<!DOCTYPE name [
<!ELEMENT name ANY>
]>
<name/>
```

-

```
<!DOCTYPE name [
<!ELEMENT name ANY>
<!ELEMENT foo (#PCDATA)>
]>
<name>
    <foo/>
</name>
```