# DTD element content

Tags: xml, dtd

In dtd, is it possible to have an element of the type:

```
<!ELEMENT name (EMPTY|CDATA)>
```

so that we can have something like this:

```
<name/> or <name>DFGHJKHGF</name>
```

??

Answer (score 1):

Similar to your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12736648/dtd-element-empty-and-any/12736830#12736830), if you define the content as `#PCDATA` the element can still be empty.

Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE doc [
<!ELEMENT doc (name+)>
<!ELEMENT name (#PCDATA)>
]>
<doc>
    <name/>
    <name>DFGHJKHGF</name>
</doc>
```

Check out the spec for more info: http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#elemdecls